# How to insert form into a panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I am building a material management program using the MetroFramework.

I trying to insert form into a panel to change form when button is click.

But my program occur Exception it is ArgumentException:

> Only top-level controls can have an owner.

I dont understand what the problem is.

I'm sorry I do not have enough English.

```
if (!MainForm.Instance.MainPanel.Controls.ContainsKey("InnerTest"))
{
    //inner Test
    InnerTest frm = new InnerTest();
    frm.TopLevel = false;
    frm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    MainForm.Instance.MainPanel.Controls.Add(frm);
    frm.Show(); // The part that causes the exception
}
```

[image: Requirements image]

[Here is my code](https://github.com/KJongHyun/DongAh).

Comment: You better put UserControls in that panel, not Forms.

Comment: You can't insert a window into a panel. Are you looking for an MDI container?

Comment: You should consider WPF instead of WinForms, it will make this sort of thing much easier to do.

Comment: Is there any way to insert it? I thought about mdi but metroframework does not support mdi, so it does not fit into existing winforms

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the ShadowType to none